# Flask application running on uwsgi server fails to load property file

Tags: python-2.7, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am running a Flask Application on uwsgi server written in python 2.7 (version).
Application is running on virtual machine which running behind nginx .
When application is installed and API is accessible to do all functionality.

After 3-4 days of ideal time, when try to access functionality or access any API ,application throws error.

Error logs :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in
 wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() 

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in
 full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) 

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in
  handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in
 full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() 

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in
  dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint]   (**req.view_args)
```

Comment: hello, try to structure the error so that it would look like error. at least select the error section and mark that as a code. this improves the readability.

Comment: so we're supposed to reverse-engineer your issue by traceback only? can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?